# How do I show CategoryName (subcategory) directly instead of Category (parent)?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of products.

```
var products = await unitOfWork.ProductRepository.GetAllWithDetailsAsync();
```

This is the model, so far so good.

```
public class ProductModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }

        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public ICollection<int> ReceiptDetailIds { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have ProductCategoryModel.

```
    public class ProductCategoryModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<int> ProductIds { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem is with the returned Category name. Instead of returning the correct data, it returns Data.Entities.Product.
In debug mode, after expanding product, I can expand Category and inside it is CategoryName - the expected string.

**How do I show CategoryName directly instead of Category?**

Comment: How are `ProductModel` and `ProductCategoryModel` related?

Comment: As Entities, Product table references ProductCategory table with a FK - ProductCategoryId,

Comment: You already have ```CategoryName``` in ```ProductModel```

Comment: "it returns Data.Entities.Product. " Where it returns? Can you show the code pls

Comment: "var products = await ...", what is the type of products, can you type it explicetly, instead of var? And can you show your Product class too pls?

Answer (score 0):

While requesting Products in your UnitOfWork include Category `.Include("Category")`

```
public class ProductModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }

        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public ICollection<int> ReceiptDetailIds { get; set; }

        public ProductCategoryModel Category { get; set; } 

        public string CategoryName => Category.CategoryName; 
    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data